# How to get overriden value of final static field in superclass' method?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a

```
class A{ public final static String S = "A"
 public void getS(){return S;}
}
class B extends A {public final static String S "B"}
```

Is it possible by reflection or something like that to return by `getS()`method value `"B"` instead of `"A"` without overriding it in subclasses in that situation:

```
B b = new B();
b.gets(); // I would like RESULT "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you override getS() in B?

If you do, then you will be able to get B instead of A.